# Borderlands Progress not saved bug

Tags: borderlands

Recently I unlocked the 4th weapon slot. I was on level 18. I properly exited the game last time and now after break of a week, the slot is no longer available. I also got fire gem for the bird, it is no more :(

It happened many times earlier but this time I lost precious stuff. What do I do? Is it a known bug?  Does a fix exist for it?

I am playing it on PC

Answer (score 1):

What platform are you playing it on? If it's a Xbox or PS3 have you checked for updates/patches for the game? I know that one exists for both the PS3 and Xbox.

Another question if you are on console, is your hard drive full? A full hard drive can also cause games to not save properly, this applies to all games and not just borderlands.

Sadly to address your lost items issue, as with many things in the digital world. When a file is saved with certain information, that's the only information that it has to access when the file is reloaded. So it is highly doubtful that you will get your items back. You'll simply have to replay that part of the game and hopefully get the same quality of item (I assume your loaded save is before the point in the game where you got your stuff).

Another possibility is that you weren't logged into your account, but under someone else's? I had that problem when roommates and I shared a PS3 and Xbox.

Comment: The platform is PC. And I am playing all offline

Comment: Have you patched the game? Do you know what version you are running?

Chances are you are logged into the same account every time you play then? Are you playing it through Steam?

Comment: No I am not playing through steam. I am downloading the patch 1.41 I hope it may work.

Comment: Are you running Windows Vista or 7? If you are you may want to make sure, depending on your account access level, that the account is allowed to "write changes" to the system. I would strongly suggest that when you launch Borderlands that you right click on the icon and select "Run as administrator". This will make sure that the program has rights to save to disk.